# Passing string values to function and returning a collection object VBA

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason the following code is not passing a string to the function but returning the collection very well if string variables are hardcoded to the function.

I get following error

> Compile error: Argument not optional

pointing to the findlastrow() in

```
Set Dimensions = findlastrow()  --line 8
```

Here is the code.

**The main sub:**

```
Sub SheetCopier()

Dim TargetlRow As Long
Dim TargetlCol As Long
Dim Tabname As String

Dim Dimensions As Collection
Set Dimensions = findlastrow()

TargetControlTab = "tab1"
Tabname = TargetControlTab


Call findlastrow(Tabname)

MsgBox "Last Row: " & Dimensions.Item(1) & vbNewLine & "Last Column: " & Dimensions.Item(2)

End Sub
```

**The function:**

```
   Function findlastrow(Tabname As String) As Collection
   'Finds the last non-blank cell in a single row or column

    Dim FilledDimensions As Collection
    Set FilledDimensions = New Collection


     Sheets(Tabname).Select
    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    TargetlRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    TargetlCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    FilledDimensions.Add TargetlRow
    FilledDimensions.Add TargetlCol

    Set findlastrow = FilledDimensions

    End Function
```

Comment: `findLastRow` has a `Tabname` argument...

Comment: Why do you expect the code to pass a string if you didn't pass anything here? `Set Dimensions = findlastrow()`

Comment: the solution could be:
 `Function findlastrow(Optional ByVal Tabname as String) As Collection`
By the way, to know the last row or last column you can use:
`xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` 
or
`xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count`

Comment: Couldnt really find how to do that, tried putting in the tabname variable in but did not work

Comment: @simo was trying to avoid ByVal usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have defined `Tabname` as the argument for your `findlastrow` function and you have tried to define it again inside the function, you cannot do that, so

remove this line: `Tabname As String`

and amend the sub as explained below:

```
Sub SheetCopier()

    Dim TargetlRow As Long
    Dim TargetlCol As Long
    Dim Tabname As String

    Dim Dimensions As Collection
'this line is the problem since you are not passing a worksheet to the function
    'Set Dimensions = findlastrow()

 TargetControlTab = "tab1"
 Tabname = TargetControlTab


 set Dimensions=findlastrow(Tabname) 

 MsgBox "Last Row: " & Dimensions.Item(1) & vbNewLine & "Last Column: " & Dimensions.Item(2)
end sub
```

Comment: @BigBen just noticed it and fixed it

Comment: That *duplicate declaration* was going to be OP's next compile error =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon the sub does not have `end sub` too, LOL

Comment: @MathieuGuindon if you mean the "tabname as string" in the function? fixed, if not can you please elaborate?

Comment: @tengee I tried the code and it is working fine, you can select it as the correct answer if you don't mind

Comment: @tengee I guess you don't need this line too since you are passing the sheet name to your function and there is no need to select it to make it work `Sheets(Tabname).Select`

Comment: @tengee I mean the compiler starts at the top and chokes on the first compile error it encounters - in your case a parameterless procedure call against a procedure requiring a parameter. The next compile error was going to be the duplicate declaration of `Tabname` in the scope of `findLastrow`, which this answer fixes.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yes it makes sense. I figured whats wrong with your conments. Thank you very much for taking the time to explain!